How to make github api request succesfull using PAT for public repositories
ode.js v20.15.0
bikidas@Biki-Das-Distinction-Mac github-api % node index.js
file:///Users/bikidas/github-api/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-bundle/index.js:106
const error = new RequestError(toErrorMessage(data), status, {
^
RequestError [HttpError]: Resource not accessible by personal access token - https://docs.github.com/rest/issues/issues#create-an-issue
at file:///Users/bikidas/github-api/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-bundle/index.js:106:21
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async requestWithGraphqlErrorHandling (file:///Users/bikidas/github-api/node_modules/@octokit/plugin-retry/dist-bundle/index.js:36:20)
at async Job.doExecute (/Users/bikidas/github-api/node_modules/bottleneck/light.js:405:18) {
status: 403,
request: {
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/Md-124/Empty/issues',
headers: {
I am trying to create issue using the create Issue post req from octoKit i want to query my friends repo and create an issue there, but using my own PAT, does that work the repo has all worflows checked of write and read permission but i am getting this error. any one knows if this is possible and what am i doing wrong?

The repo is public. Therefore you should be able to create an issue in it.
Your PAT needs a repo scope in order to create an issue via GitHub API.
